# Safari interprets Objects from xhr request as String not as Objects

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to load a json file with objects via xhr request.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "jsonp";
    xhr.onload = function (data) {
        discog = xhr.response;
    };

    xhr.send();
```

this works fine in chrome, safari however interprets the response as a string - what am I doing wrong here?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `"jsonp"` is not a [valid `responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseType).

Try this instead:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.onload = function(){
    discog = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

Or this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.onload = function(){
    discog = xhr.response;
};
xhr.send();
```